# "Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master "

Tags: homebrew, blockchain

while installing homebrew this error comes after 60% download..

```
 * [new tag]             3.6.5                   -> 3.6.5
 * [new tag]             3.6.6                   -> 3.6.6
 * [new tag]             3.6.7                   -> 3.6.7
 * [new tag]             3.6.8                   -> 3.6.8
 * [new tag]             3.6.9                   -> 3.6.9
HEAD is now at 106af0355 Merge pull request #14337 from Red54/patch-2
==> Tapping homebrew/core
remote: Enumerating objects: 1391130, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (411/411), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (218/218), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.
error: 4802 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

How to fix this error??